# Various kinds of derivatives

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, distribution-theory, lp-spaces

Let $f\colon \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a measurable function. Let us introduce the following notions of "derivative" of $f$.

1. **Classical derivative**. The unique function $f'_c$ defined pointwise by the following:$$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{ f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}- f'_c(x)=0,\qquad \forall x \in \mathbb{R},$$provided that the limit exists at all points.
2. **$L^p$ derivative**. For a fixed $p\in (1, \infty)$, the unique function $f'_p$ such that $$\lim_{h\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left\lvert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'_p(x)\right\rvert^p\, dx=0,$$provided that $f\in L^p$ and that such a function $f'_p$ exists.
3. **Distributional derivative**. The unique distribution $f'_d$ such that $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\phi'(x)\, dx=-\langle f'_d, \phi\rangle, \qquad \forall \phi \in C^\infty_0(\mathbb{R}),$$
   provided that $f$ defines a distribution (i.e., $f\in L^1_{\mathrm{loc}}$).

The vague version of my question is:

> to what extent are these definitions mutually consistent?

More precisely:

1. Suppose that $f'_c$ exists (at all points) and $f'_c \in L^p$. Is it true that $f'_p$ exists and $f'_c=f'_p$?
2. Suppose that $f$ defines a distribution, that $f'_c$ exists at all points and that $f'_c$ defines a distribution. Is it true that $f'_d=f'_c$?
3. Suppose that $f'_p$ exists. Is it true that $f'_p=f'_d$?
4. Suppose that $f'_d$ is a continuous function. Is is true that $f'_c$ exists and $f'_c=f'_d$?
5. (*Suggested by Tomasz in comments*) Suppose that $f'_d\in L^p$. Is it true that $f'_p$ exists and that $f'_p=f'_d$?

**P.S.**: Some information on this topic, and especially on question 3, can be found on the book *An introduction to nonlinear dispersive equations* by F.Linares and G.Ponce, Springer Universitext. Look for Exercise 1.9 on page 21.

Comment: Why do you assume that $f'_d$ is a continuous function in 4.? Classical derivatives can be rather discontinuous.

Comment: @tomasz: It's for simplicity purposes. If you want you can replace the assumption with something weaker. The philosophy is: is there some property $P$ such that $$f'_d\ \text{satisfies property P}\ \Rightarrow\ f'_c\ \text{exists and is equal to}\ f'_d\ ?$$

Comment: I believe that it's enough to assume that it is integrable to get $f$ to have an almost-everywhere classical derivative; also, I think you forgot to ask about the case where $f_d'$ is in $L^p$ -- whether or not this implies that $f_p'$ exists (and equals $f_d'$) -- unless this is obvious for some reason, in which case you should still write it down explicitly so that the others can learn about it.

Comment: @tomasz: It is not obvious at all, if you want to edit the question to add the missing case you are most welcome.

Comment: @tomasz: I've edited the question to add your interesting contribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Partial answer:

1. is true:
   \begin{multline}
   \int_{\bf R} \left\lvert \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-f'_c(x)\right\rvert^p\, dx\leq\frac{1}{h}\int_{\bf R}\int_0^h \left\lvert f'_c(x+t)-f'_c(x)\right\rvert^p\,dt \, dx=\\
   =\frac{1}{h}\int_0^h\int_{\bf R} \left\lvert f'_c(x+t)-f'_c(x)\right\rvert^p\,dx \, dt
   \end{multline}
   And the last expression tends to zero as $h\to 0$ (because translations are continuous in $L^p$).
2. is true -- this is a simple application of product rule and fundamental theorem of calculus. It is applicable, because an everywhere differentiable function with integrable derivative is absolutely continuous.
3. I don't really know.
4. is true (up to a modification on a measure zero set). Consider $g(x)=\int_0^x f'_d$. Then $g$ is a $C^1$ function, and $f'_d$ is its classical derivative, and hence it's also its distributional derivative, so $f-g$ has weak derivative zero, so it must be constant (up to a set of measure zero), so $f$ is a $C^1$ function up to a set of measure $0$.

Comment: 2. is not really so simple, I'd say. If $f\in C^1$, then I agree, but as you point out, a classical derivative can be very discontinuous. Your argument does work for locally-absolutely continuous functions, though. I think that for functions which are differentiable but are not absolutely continuous 2. is false.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: If I recall correctly, differentiable functions with integrable derivatives are always absolutely continuous. I believe the assumption that the function be differentiable *everywhere* is essential.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: you can find the theorem in Rudin's *Real and complex analysis*, in the chapter on fundamental theorem of calculus.

Comment: I have found the theorem, thank you. It is Theorem 7.21 of the 3rd edition.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I just noticed that I implicitly used the theorem in the first point as well – the fundamental theorem is applicable there because an $L^p$ function is locally integrable.

Answer (score 10):

Let's begin with some preliminaries.

For a locally integrable function $g$, let $\iota_g$ denote the distribution $\varphi \mapsto \int g(x)\varphi(x)\,dx$ (when we want to distinguish between the function and the induced distribution, otherwise we also denote the distribution with $g$). Let $D$ be the distributional derivative operator, i.e. $DT[\varphi] = -T[\varphi']$. For an integrable function $h$, let $I(h) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty h(x)\,dx$. Let $u$ be your favourite test function with integral $1$. Then we can write every test function $\varphi$ as $\varphi = I(\varphi)\cdot u + \eta'$, where $\eta(x) = \int_{-\infty}^x \varphi(t) - I(\varphi)u(t)\,dt$.
We have the

**Lemma:** If $T$ is a distribution such that $DT = \iota_g$ for a locally integrable function $g$, then $T = \iota_{G+c}$ where $G(x) = \int_0^x g(t)\,dt$ and $c$ is an appropriate constant.

**Proof:** $G$ is a continuous (absolutely continuous, even) function; its distributional derivative is $\iota_g$:

$$\begin{align}
D\iota_G[\varphi] &= - \int_{-\infty}^\infty G(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx\\
&= -\int_0^\infty \left(\int_0^xg(t)\,dt\right) \varphi'(x)\,dx + \int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\int_x^0g(t)\,dt\right) \varphi'(x)\,dx\\
&= \int_0^\infty \left(\int_t^\infty (-\varphi'(x))\,dx\right) g(t)\,dt + \int_{-\infty}^0 \left(\int_{-\infty}^t \varphi'(x)\,dx\right) g(t)\,dt\\
&= \int_0^\infty\varphi(t)g(t)\,dt + \int_{-\infty}^0 \varphi(t)g(t)\,dt\\
&= \iota_g[\varphi].
\end{align}$$

Let $c := T[u] - \iota_G[u]$. Then $T = \iota_{G+c}$:

$$\begin{align}
\iota_{G+c}[\varphi] &= \iota_{G+c}[I(\varphi)\cdot u + \eta']\\
&= I(\varphi)\iota_{G+c}[u] - D\iota_{G+c}[\eta]\\
&= I(\varphi)(\iota_G[u] + c) - \iota_g[\eta]\\
&= I(\varphi)T[u] - DT[\eta]\\
&= I(\varphi)T[u] + T[\eta']\\
&= T[I(\varphi)\cdot u + \eta']\\
&= T[\varphi].
\end{align}$$

Together with the fact that for a locally integrable function $g$ we have $\iota_g = 0 \iff g = 0\: [\text{a.e.}]$, that will give us a stronger form of 4. and it's also useful in 2. and 5.

1. We have the somewhat stronger result that it suffices that $f'_c$ exists almost everywhere and $f$ be absolutely continuous. The proof [tomasz](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/30222/tomasz) [gave](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/352466/83702) covers that situation.
2. See the first part of the proof of the lemma. The integral of $f_c'$ has distributional derivative $\iota_{f_c'}$. But under the hypotheses that $f_c'$ exists everywhere, $f$ is the integral of $f_c'$ (plus a constant), so $f_c' = f_d'$.
3. Also true. Let $\displaystyle q_h(f)(x) =\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. The assumption is that $q_h(f) \to f_p'$ in $L^p$, but then $q_h(f) \to f_p'$ in $\mathscr{D}'$. But $q_h(f) \to Df$ in $\mathscr{D}'$, so $\iota_{f_p'} =D\iota_f$. We can also see that without theory: $$\begin{align}
   \int_{-\infty}^\infty f_p'(x)\varphi(x)\,dx &= \lim_{h\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty q_h(f)(x)\varphi(x)\,dx\qquad \left(\varphi \in L^q\right)\\
   &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(f(x+h) - f(x)\right)\varphi(x)\,dx\\
   &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac1h \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\left(\varphi(x-h) - \varphi(x) \right)\,dx\\
   &= \lim_{h\to 0} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) \frac{\varphi(x-h)-\varphi(x)}{h}\,dx\\
   &= - \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\varphi'(x)\,dx\qquad \left(q_{-h}(\varphi) \to \varphi' \text{ in } L^q\right)
   \end{align}$$
4. By the lemma, if $f_d'$ is locally integrable, then $f$ is (almost everywhere) the integral of $f_d'$ (plus a constant), so $f$ is differentiable at least in all Lebesgue points of $f_d'$ with $f_c'(x) = f_d'(x)$ there. If $f$ and $f_d'$ are continuous, then $f$ is everywhere differentiable with derivative $f_c' = f_d'$.
5. Of course $f_d' \in L^p$ does not imply that $f\in L^p$, so that needs to be an additional assumption. But if $f \in L^p$ and $f_d' \in L^p$, then, by 4., $f$ is - possibly after modification on a null set - the integral of $f_d'$ and $f$ is almost everywhere differentiable, so the more general version of point 1. yields that $f_p'$ exists and equals $f_c' = f_d'$.