# When an ordinary partial derivative is a Frechet derivative on a Banach space?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

We have a function $p(x, \theta)\in \mathbb{R},\ x\in\mathbb{R},\ \theta\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

We can also consider $p(\cdot, \theta)$ to be a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to a Banach space of functions. For example, assuming $p(\cdot, \theta)\in \mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ for each $\theta$ we have that $\hat p:\theta\to p(\cdot, \theta)$ is a map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

My question is about relation of the ordinary partial derivative $\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}$ (assuming it is $\in\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$)  to the Frechet derivative of $\hat p:\theta\to p(\cdot, \theta)$. When are they the same?

**Addition after the comments of Zerox:**

For the ordinary partial derivative for each $x$
$$
\lim_{d\theta\to0}\frac{\left|p(x,\theta+d\theta)-p(x, \theta)-\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta\right|}{\Vert d\theta \Vert}=0
$$
For the Frechet derivative we have different convergence
$$\lim_{d\theta\to0}\frac{\Vert p(\cdot,\theta+d\theta)-p(\cdot, \theta)-L(d\theta)\Vert_{\mathbb{L}^1}}{\Vert d\theta\Vert}=0$$
where $L(d\theta)$ is a continuous linear map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$.

The linear map $d\theta\to\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ is continuous in the Banach norm.
$$\left\|\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta\right\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}=\left\|\sum_i\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}d\theta_i\right\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}\leq\sum_i\left\Vert\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}\right\Vert_{\mathbb{L}^1}|d\theta_i|\leq\operatorname{max}_i\left\Vert\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}\right\|_{\mathbb{L}^1}\Vert d\theta\Vert_{\mathbb{L}^1}$$

So this map seems to be a candidate for $L(d\theta)$, but i don't see why (or when) they have to coincide. Pointwise convergence (in $x$) doesn't imply $\mathbb{L}^1$ convergence and vice versa.

Of course in the topology of pointwise convergence on the Banach space they would coincide, but i am interested in the $\mathbb{L}^1$ convergence.

**A special case of parametrized probability density functions:**

If there are no convenient conditions for the general case, then maybe there are some for this case?
$$\int p(x,\theta)dx=1,\ p(x,\theta)\geq0\ \forall\theta$$

**Upd:** deleted the incorrect Scheffe's Lemma application.

**The case of dominated partial derivatives:**

Assume $\left|\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}\right|\leq g(x)$ for some $g(x)\in \mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$. Then by the multivariate MVT
$$
\begin{split}
\frac{\left|p(x,\theta+d\theta)-p(x, \theta)-\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta\right|}{\Vert d\theta\Vert}\leq&\frac{\left|\frac{\partial p(x, c)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta\right|+\left|\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta\right|}{\Vert d\theta\Vert}\\
\leq&\left\Vert\frac{\partial p(x, c)}{\partial\theta}\right\Vert+\left\Vert\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\right\Vert\leq2\sqrt n g(x)
\end{split}
$$
So the whole expression is also dominated by the $\mathbb{L}^1(\mathbb{R})$ function.

By the dominated convergence theorem we have the convergence of the expression above in $\mathbb{L}^1$, so $L(d\theta)=\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta$.

**If both derivatives exist, they have to be equal:**

One more observation. For any $\mathbb R \ni h_m\to0$ the existence of the Frechet derivative implies the $\mathbb L^1$ convergence to $0$ of the corresponding expression for each $i=1,\cdots,n$.
$$
\left\Vert\frac{p(\cdot,\theta+e_ih_m)-p(\cdot, \theta)}{h_m}-L(e_i)\right\Vert_{\mathbb{L}^1}\to0$$
Where $e_i$ is $i$th vector of the standard basis.

Then there exists a subsequence of $h_m$, call it $\mathbb R \ni g_l\to0$, for which the expression above converges pointwise a.e. to $0$.
$$\left|\frac{p(x,\theta+e_ig_l)-p(x, \theta)}{g_l}-L(e_i)(x)\right|\to0\ \textbf{a.e.}$$
But we also have for the ordinary partial derivative
$$\left|\frac{p(x,\theta+e_ig_l)-p(x, \theta)}{g_l}-\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}\right|\to0$$

So $L(e_i)=\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta_i}$and thus $L(d\theta)=\frac{\partial p(\cdot, \theta)}{\partial\theta}\cdot d\theta$.

**Additions, corrections, indications of errors are still welcome.**

Comment: They are never the same: the Fréchet derivative at $\theta$ is a bounded linear map from $\Bbb{R}^n$ to $L^1(\Bbb{R})$, while the ordinary partial derivative at $\theta$ is just a function from $\Bbb{R}$ to $\Bbb{R}^{n \times (n+1)}$.

Comment: @Zerox but the ordinary differential $\frac{\partial p(x, \theta)}{\theta}d\theta$ is actually a bounded liner map from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$. So i mean in this sense.

Comment: In what sense is the ordinary derivative a bounded linear map? You should write down in your decription, and maybe you will find the two definitions of ordinary and Fréchet coincide.

Comment: For example, I would rather view $\dfrac{\partial f(\vec{x}, \vec{y})}{\partial \vec{y}}$ as a matrix function $\left( \dfrac{\partial f_i}{\partial y_j} \right)$ of size $(\dim \vec{x} + \dim \vec{y}) \times \dim \vec{y}$.

Comment: @Zerox updated my question, the problem that convergencies in the definition of the derivatives are different (pointwise vs $L^1$) and one doesn't imply the other.

Comment: Now I know what you mean, except that $L(d \theta)$ should be in $L^1(\Bbb{R})$, not $L(\Bbb{R}^n)$.

Comment: Yes, this was a mistake, fixed.

Comment: [This old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352307/8157) is related.

Comment: I deleted my answer since it seems to me that the question is simpler than I thought: my advice is nevertheless to have a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/349057/question-about-functional-derivatives/349584#349584) to get a precise picture.

Comment: @Daniele Tampieri
 sorry, i really don't see how your link is helpful. I mean i even wrote the definitions of the derivatives in question.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro thank you. Is your point 1 adaptable to my case? Also maybe you could clarify how to show convergence to 0 in tomasz's answer for point 1?

Comment: ok, i see why the convergence happens. Still not sure if that answer is adaptable for my case...