# What is the relationship between almost everywhere differentiable and Frechet differentiable???

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-measure, banach-spaces, frechet-derivative

Suppoce for every $u$, $f(u)$ is a square integrable function, namely, $f(u)\in L^2([0,1])$. We can compute the Frechet derivative of this functional $f$, or in other words, the condition for $f$ to be Frechet differentiable is
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left( \left\|f(u+h)-f(u)-hf'(u) \right\| \right)=0.
$$

However, we can also compute the derivative for $f$ with the index $s$ fixed. Say, for a fixed $s\in[0,1]$, $f(u;s)$ will only be a mapping from $[0,1]$ to $R$. We can also compute the partial derivative of $u$ and the differentiable condition will be
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{1}{h}\left(f(u+h;s)-f(u;s)-hf'(u;s) \right)=0.
$$
We can therefore require the above equation (with $s$ fixed) exists for every $s\in[0,1]$ and also obtain the derivative $f'(u;s)$. Namely, we compute this derivative pointwisely.

My question is: what is the relationship between these two differentiable conditions???

Based on my intuition, I believe the later is sufficient to prove the former, but the contray may not exist. Moreover, the second equation should exist for almost everywhere $s\in[0,1]$ instead of the strictly every $s\in[0,1]$. (It is just my guess).

To prove my guess, note that the first condition needs
$$
\lim_{h\to 0}\int_0^1\frac{1}{h^2}\left(f(u+h;s)-f(u;s)-hf'(u;s) \right)^2 ds=0.
$$
The second simply interchanges the $\lim$ and the integral.(With $\lim$ first and integral second). We can use Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem to prove this problem. However, since our limit is simply $0$, I believe the dominated convergence theorem will strengthen the condtion. In fact, we should not need such a strict condition.(I guess it...)

I wonder also is there any reference talking about this question comprehensively?

Thanks for every kind of help!!!It torments me for a long time(cry...)

Comment: I believe this is relevant - https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350118/when-an-ordinary-partial-derivative-is-a-frechet-derivative-on-a-banach-space

Comment: @Koncopd Thanks for your kind help! I have read your post carefully. It is just the question I want to ask. But the update in the post seems to only show their equality known their existence? There seems not to be any micro attention paid to their inclusion relation? Say, whether one can prove the other, or which one will be easier to statisfy, or under which conditions they will not be equal?

Comment: I have that in the section "The case of dominated partial derivatives".

Comment: For me, the role of $s$ is not clear. What is $f(u;s)$? Do you mean $(f(u))(s)$? But this is not well defined since $f(u) \in L^2([0,1])$ is only an equivalence class.

Comment: @gerw Sorry for my unclear notations! I do not quite understand the reason that you say $(f(u))(s)$ is not well defined. For each fixed $u$, $f(u)$ is still a integrable function on interval $[0,1]$. And my token $s$ represents variable on this  interval. Could you please kindly tell me the meaning of your 'equivalence class'? Thank you very much!!!