# From partial derivative of real-valued function to Fréchet derivative of Banach-space valued function

Tags: functional-analysis, frechet-derivative

Consider a bivariate, real-valued function $u \colon X \times Y \to \mathbb{R}$, with
$X, Y \subset \mathbb{R}$. Assume that $u$ is differentiable in the second variable
on $X \times Y$, hence $\partial_y u(x,y)$ exists for all $(x,y) \in X \times Y$.
Note that I do not want to make any additional hypothesis on the existence of
$\partial_x u$.

Define an operator
$$
  U \colon Y \to V, \qquad y \mapsto u(\cdot,y),
$$
where $V$ is a Banach space of functions defined on $X$.

This question is about finding a connection, if at all possible, between the partial
derivative $\partial_y u$ of $u$ and the Fréchet derivative $d U$of $U$. For
instance, assume that one proves that the following operator is bounded on $Y$ to
$V$,
$$ 
A \colon y \mapsto \partial_y u(\cdot,y),
$$
then one may hope that the Fréchet derivative of $U$ at $y \in Y$ coincides with
$A(y)$, that is, $dU(y) = A(y)$.

To me, however, this may require some additional conditions. From the
definition of partial derivative of $u$ we know that
$$
u(x,y+h) - u(x,y) - \partial_y u(x,y)h = o(|h|) \qquad \text{as $h \to 0$ for all $x \in
X$}
$$
hence
$$
\lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{|u(x,y+h) - u(x,y) - \partial_y u(x,y)h|}{|h|} = 0 \qquad
\text{for all $x \in X$,}
$$
and what we must deduce is
$$
\lim_{|h| \to 0} \frac{\|u(\cdot,y+h) - u(\cdot,y) - \partial_y
u(\cdot,y)h\|_{V}}{|h|} = 0.
$$

I can't see why this would be true without further assumptions, for instance, for $V
= C(X)$. Do you have any ideas when this is true, or should I just give up and think
on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: You would need some uniformity in $x$.

Comment: Thanks @copper.hat. Indeed that is the condition I envisage missing for $V = C(D)$, but in general, which uniformity do I need? Could a hypothesis on the second partial derivative $\partial_y^2 u$ work?

Comment: similar https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4350118/when-an-ordinary-partial-derivative-is-a-frechet-derivative-on-a-banach-space

Comment: thank you @Koncopd