# function with summable derivative is uniformly continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, uniform-continuity

If we have the function 
 $f: I \to \mathbb{R}$ with derivative $f’: I \to \mathbb{R}$ 
 such that: 
 $I \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ 
 $f’ \in L^{1}(I)$ 
can we deduce that $f$ is uniformly continuous? 
Of course it is true if $I 
$ is compact since $f$ is continuous in $I$ and we can use Heine Cantor theorem; it is also true if $f’$ is bounded. But what happens when $I$ is not compact and $f’$ is unbounded and summable in $I$? 
I tried to demonstrate that the implication holds but I failed, so I tried to find a counterexample taking $I$ as a countable union of non-overlapping intervals such that $ I $ is unbounded and $|I| < +\infty $ but I failed again. Can someone help me? Thank you

Comment: The answer depends on what notion of derivative you're using. Do you mean a pointwise a.e. derivative? Or a distributional/weak derivative?

Comment: I mean a pointwise a.e. derivative

Comment: Then the answer is no: Consider $f$ the indicator function of an interval.

Comment: @Jose27, I think the OP meant to refer to a differentiable (rather than a.e. differentiable) function (otherwise there is no basis for claiming that either the function or the derivative will be bounded on a compact interval).  It seems like a legitimate question.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**. It is enough to assume $I=[0, \infty)$ and you can also assume $f(0)=0$. You then have the formula
$$\tag{1}
f(x)=\int_0^x f'(t)\, dt.$$
Use this to study the increment $f(x)-f(y)$.

**IMPORTANT REMARK**. As Jose27 pointed out in comments to the main question, it is important to specify the notion of derivative we are talking about. The formula (1) holds if $f'$ is a *distributional derivative*, provided that $f'$ is an integrable function. It is actually an if and only if. That is,
$$ 
\text{(1) holds} \iff f' \text{ is the distributional derivative of }f \text{ and }f'\text{ is integrable.}$$

In this case, it is said that $f$ is *absolutely continuous*.

[This old question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/352307/8157) deals exactly with this subject.